# Tensorflow gradient returning null

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to implement the tutorial given on [Tensorflow tutorial on custom training](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training). Due to some reason dW and DB is None. I am not getting why t.gradient() is returning None.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

class Model(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.W = tf.Variable(5.0)
        self.b = tf.Variable(0.0)
    def __call__(self,x):
        return self.W*x+self.b
    def loss_function(self, y_true, y_predicted):
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_predicted-y_true))
    def train(self, inputs, outputs, learning_rate):
        with tf.GradientTape() as t:
            current_loss = self.loss_function(inputs,outputs)
        dW,db = t.gradient(current_loss,[self.W, self.b])
        ## dW and db returns None
        self.W.assign_sub(learning_rate*dW)
        self.b.assign_sub(learning_rate*db)
```

But the following code works fine when train is not a method of model. Any reason why?

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

class Model(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.W = tf.Variable(5.0)
        self.b = tf.Variable(0.0)
    def __call__(self,x):
        return self.W*x+self.b
    def loss_function(self, y_true, y_predicted):
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_predicted-y_true))

def train(model, inputs, outputs, learning_rate):
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        current_loss = model.loss_function(model(inputs),outputs)
    dW,db = t.gradient(current_loss,[model.W, model.b])
    ## dW and db returns None
    model.W.assign_sub(learning_rate*dW)
    model.b.assign_sub(learning_rate*db)
```

Answer (score 1):

For `gradient` to work, the whole graph needs to be crafted within the scope of `GradientTape`.

For example, in the code provided in [Tensorflow tutorial on custom training](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training):

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    current_loss = model.loss_function(model(inputs),outputs)
```

The graph where `current_loss` is connected to the model variables (`model.W` and `model.B`) are constructed within the scope of `t`.

If you change the codes provided by the tutorial as follows:

```
logits = model(inputs)
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    current_loss = model.loss_function(logits, outputs)
```

You will get `None` for `dW` and `db`.

Comment: Is this because the GradientTape does not watch constant?. Does Tensorflow consider the computed tensor as variable or constant?